# How to coordinate subversion client configuration?

Tags: svn, configuration

As a subversion user you'll have a local configuration folder */<userhome>/.subversion/* in your user home. In there is a *config* file containing, among others, ***auto-props***.

These properties are applied to files that you add to the repository, e.g. by

```
svn add <file>
```

Now here's my question (actually two questions):

1. How do you coordinate your development team so that they always use the same *auto-props* in your project? I know that there is a [feature request](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1974) registered at [tirgis.org](http://subversion.tigris.org). But that's sheduled for svn 2.0 , so what's your intermediate solution to this issue?
2. In case you are working on separate projects from different svn servers: How do you organize your *auto-props* configurations to handle different settings per server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it this way:

We have an pre-commit-hookscript monitoring all possible properties for each file based on file type and we give an errormessage back to the client with an URL where to obtain the current version of the config file.

It is also possible to parse this online config file, so you do not have to maintain your hook script *and* the standard config file.

Comment: Any chance that you'd share your pre-commit script?